# tex4ebook: How to align text justified

Tags: alignment, tex4ebook, ebook, epub

Normally, documents created with the `book` class have their text aligned justified.

`tex4ebook` seems to ignore that. Is this on purpose, as the alignment will be set by the e-readers? Would some default value make sense, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers and ebook readers don't use TeX's line-breaking algorithm, so the justified text doesn't look as good. Moreover, I have read some recommendations that letting users choose their preferences regarding font families, sizes, or justification is better. So, by default, we don't set justification at all. If you want to set it, you can use this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{p{
 text-align: justify;
 hyphens: auto;
}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This enables justification for paragraphs and also enables hyphenation, which should make the paragraphs look better if the reader supports hyphenation.

I've made a small MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

And this is the result in Calibre:

[image]

It doesn't support hyphens, so there are too big spaces on some lines.

This is the result in Firefox:

[image]

It supports hyphenation, so it looks a bit better.

Comment: Nice, thanks for your fast reply! I'll again look into whether justification is sensible, then.
To my knowledge, for hyphenation, the HTML language attribute needs to be set. Is this done with your code already? Does this need to be adjusted in case of a different language (like German, for example)?

Comment: @clel the language should be set, `tex4ebook` supports Babel, so if you select German as a main language, it should be set for the book as well.